# $routeProvider - modal of a single page with different URL

Tags: angularjs, routes, modal-dialog, route-provider

I have a list of items showed in a page. The idea is to click on an item, and open a modal showing the information of the selected item, and in the background the list remains.
When the modal opens, the URL should change. So the idea would be to have a specific URL for every item, so when you access the url, you should see the modal, with the item info and in the background the main page.

```
I'm using $routeProvider for routing.
```

> Example:
>
> I would like to have something similar to this
>
> http://www.eltrecetv.com.ar/articulo/le-salio-del-alma-el-emotivo-recuerdo-de-la-china-suarez-para-su-papa-en-una-fecha_087466

[image]

```
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    })
    .when('/meals', {
        templateUrl: 'views/meals/meals.html',
        controller: 'MealsCtrl'
    })
    .when('/meal/:mealId', {
        templateUrl: 'views/meals/meal-profile.html',
        controller: 'MealCtrl'
    })
```

The **/meal/:mealId** should be shown in a modal, and the URL should change when the modal is opened.

I've searched a lot, but I couldn't find a suitable answer for this.

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: can you explain a bit more.

Comment: I add some code and and image explaining what I would like to achieve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify states you want to show as modal and when it is handled, return to state you want to. For example:-

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {      
 $stateProvider.state('tasks', {
url: '/tasks',
templateUrl: 'tasks.html',
controller: 'TasksCtrl'

 url: "/tasks/:id",
 onEnter: function($stateParams, $state, $modal) {
   $modal.open({
    templateUrl: "show.html",
    resolve: {},
    controller: function($scope, $state) {
      $scope.ok = function () {
        $scope.$close();
      };              
      $scope.dismiss = function () {
        $scope.$dismiss();
      };
    }
  }).result.then(function (result) { 
     // $scope.$close
  }, function (result) { 
     // $scope.$dismiss
  }).finally(function () { 
    // finally
    return $state.transitionTo("tasks");
  });
  }
 });
 });
```

Here is plunker code for it : [code](http://plnkr.co/edit/fCyrlH)
I will edit my answer for routeProvider also.

Comment: I was going to ask you that, if there's a solution for routeProvider. Cool If you can provide both answers. Thanks mate!

Comment: unfortunetely routeProvider can't be used in this case. because of reason that If you SPA has multiple part on page which you need to render on some condition, In this $routeProvider fails.(In such cases we need to go for directive like ng-include, ng-switch, ng-if, ng-show actually which looks bad as thinking of SPA).

Comment: I'm starting to make this work! The only issue that I find is that the $modal is now named $uibModal. When I make it work, I'll post it in there, and select this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Ask me if you want any kind of help.